# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown by cursor.getString()

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, android-cursor

I use one in my sqlite database a config table. This has the following composition:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CONFIG_CREATE = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONFIGS
    + "("
        + CONFIG_HIDDEN_CATEGORIES + " TEXT DEFAULT '1,2' NULL"
    + ");";
```

Later I try to access with the following code:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_CONFIGS, new String[] {DatabaseHelper.CONFIG_HIDDEN_CATEGORIES}, null, null, null, null, null);
try {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int test = cursor.getCount();

    String data = cursor.getString(0);

}
catch (Exception exception) {
```

But the line `cursor.getString(0)` throws the following exeption (variable test is 0):

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0

when I run the following code, the column `CONFIG_HIDDEN_CATEGORIES` is displayed to me...  what is wrong?

```
    Cursor dbCursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_CONFIGS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String[] columnNames = dbCursor.getColumnNames(); // index 0 is the value of CONFIG_HIDDEN_CATEGORIES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that your `Cursor` is empty. You should wrap your actions to correct condition:

```
try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("columnName"));
       // do your stuff
    }
    else {
       // cursor is empty
    }
}
...
```

Your actual code won't work correct because you just calling `moveToFirst()` method but you don't know (are not testing) if it'll return true or false.

Your code works correct only if `Cursor` is not empty. In second case it won't work.

**Note:** I recommend you to use `getColumnIndex(<columnName>)` method for getting column index due to its name. This method is safer and more human-readable.

Comment: ok, but why is the `cursor`empty? I don't modify the table... and the default value is 1,2

Comment: @David so your database is empty e.q. has no row.